# Upload stuck on Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just made Google Chrome Extension and created a .zip file from it. Then when I am trying to upload it, its taking forever to do anything.

http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3370/20101208022006.png

Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago (are you at the latest developer branch)? When this happened I also got permissions error when I was trying to access desktop from file upload dialog. Restarting the computer helped.